Xcode 15.3 hangs up right after being installed on Sonoma
Installed Xcode from Apple Store on my Sonoma 14.4.1, opened it, tried to check iOS 17.4 and it hung up forever displaying colored round cursor:

The same happens when I press "Install" button.
What can cause this? Is there some log files I can check?
When I download Xcode as "xip" archive I get the same effect.
Tried to download older Xcode version, but it is not compatible with Sonoma.
After doing some further attempts I notices that it hang up after it starts even if I did not check or press some buttons and Settings menu item is disabled:

Activity Monitor:

Storage->Developer displays this:

Delete button is disabled when I select Command Line Tools.

You can do the installation under more controlled conditions thru Xcode preferences.

@matt  Settings menu item is disabled, see updated post.

I would try going to memory management (system settings) and under developer, delete all the old ones. then try to install the new ones.

@johnelemans What can be wrong in system memory settings? They display 16GB RAM, Intel i7 and 220 GB free disk space. Also see the screenshot of Activity Monitor. And there are no old SDKs, at least folder /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs does not exist.

That is not where SDKs live. They are in your top-level /Library/Develop/CoreSimulator (not the user library). That is the whole point of the exercise: that is the installation you are attempting to perform.

It probably wouldn't hurt to get rid of the command line tools, since there is little point having them if you also have Xcode.

@matt QT requires them see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/ios-building-from-source.html, but I tried to install XCode first and when XCode failed to install SDKs I started to do various experiments and installed Command Line Tools among other things. So first time I did a clean XCode installation right after recovering my system.

But QT is not in the question. Also, what does "recovering my system" mean here? Was there some earlier issue you forgot to tell us about. — Try to imagine that no one is having this issue except for you. So you need to tell us what we would have to do in order to have the issue.

sorry, I meant storage settings not memory. it's jus a quick way of getting rid of Xcode cruft.
